# How to rerender a a component in angular after a value has been updated through subscribing a subject()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, subject, rerender

I would like to re-render a component after I receive a value from a different component. This is the code I use to receive the value:

```
this.service.value.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSignal.asObservable()),
    ).subscribe(data => {
        this.item = value
        //would like to rerender my component upon receiving value;  
    });
```

Comment: Try to provide your code in https://stackblitz.com and this will help others to solve your issue

Comment: We need some info. It's hard debugging some angular without all infos ... You do the subscription in an external component or even in a service or the same component (where you want to rerender) ?

Comment: just you can use *ngIf, see https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#conditional-display-with-ngif:  `<your-component *ngIf="item"></your-component>`